# From decorator, access scope of module in which decorator is invoked

Tags: python, scope, python-decorators

I have a module of decorators in `my_decorators.py` which are creating classes and I am importing these decorators into `Example.py` to use on methods of the `Example` class:

`my_decorators.py`

```
def my_decorator():
    def inner_decorator(func):
        class CreatedClass(object):
            something = 'something'
        return CreatedClass
    return inner_decorator
```

`Example.py`

```
class Example(object):
    # I WANT TO ACCESS THIS SCOPE IN THE DECORATOR
    @my_decorator
    to_belong_to_newly_created_class(self):
        pass
```

Is there a way to access the local or global scope of `Example` class or of the `Example.py` module inside the decorator in the separate module?

Comment: Why do you want to access that scope? If you need access to `to_belong_to_newly_created_class`, that's `func`. You already have access to that. - EDIT: wait, no, you defined the arguments wrong. But you *would* have access to it as the argument to the decorator if you'd defined the arguments right.

Comment: Do I have access to `self` (referring to the instance of `Example`) inside of the decorator? If I do, how do I access it?

Comment: There is no instance of `Example` when the decorator executes.

Comment: What is this decorator actually supposed to do? What is the role of `CreatedClass`? When is the definition of `CreatedClass` supposed to be executed, and what should happen to `CreatedClass` once it's defined? Your decorator doesn't make much sense, and you haven't given much explanation for what it's supposed to do, so it's hard to say what it *should* look like.

Comment: Is the `to_belong_to_newly_created_class` method supposed to be a method of `Example`, a method of `CreatedClass`, or something else? Is `CreatedClass` supposed to be accessible through an attribute of `Example`? Or is `to_belong_to_newly_created_class` supposed to be a method that creates instances of `CreatedClass`? It's really unclear what the intended result of any of this was.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_decorator(f):
    def inner_decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.TEST) # Access the required member from self.
        class CreatedClass(object):
            something = 'something'
        return CreatedClass
    return inner_decorator


class Example(object):
    TEST = 'TEST!!'
    # I WANT TO ACCESS THIS SCOPE IN THE DECORATOR
    @my_decorator
    def to_belong_to_newly_created_class(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = Example()
    print(ex.to_belong_to_newly_created_class())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TEST!!
<class '__main__.my_decorator.<locals>.inner_decorator.<locals>.CreatedClass'>
```